# Downgrade Rails 4.2.1 to Rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was wondering what we be the best way to downgrade Rails from `4.2.1` to `4.0.2`. At the moment my plan is to delete my gemfile.lock and change

```
gem 'rails', 4.2.1' to gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
```

But I can see issues arising such as `Railties` and the way my `application.rb`, `development.rb` files are constructed

Example

`Rails 4.2.1`

```
# Development.rb
Rails.application.configure do

end
```

`Rails 4.0.2`

```
# Development.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do

end
```

`Rails 4.2.1`

```
# Application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

`Rails 4.0.2`

```
# Application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

Is this to big of a jump or is there a safe way to do this?

EDIT

So after following the answer the first issue i get when trying to start my app is

```
`require': cannot load such file -- active_job/railtie (LoadError)
```

Comment: why would you like to downgrade @richlewis

Comment: well it might turn out to be the case that i dont now, but i am testing a theory out as thought there was a bug with asset_sync. Turns out it may not be the case

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to use any ruby version manager i.e. [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

and use rvm

```
rvm use 2.1.2
```

and then install a new gemset

```
 rails create gemset rails4.0
```

and use gemset by

```
rails use 2.1.2@rails4.0
```

and the change in your Gemfile and remove Gemfile.lock as per your need and then run fresh `bundle`

bundle

Hope it will be a fresh and separate gems and It will work well. Give it a try.